# How to create a function in MySQL that will return a random bool

Tags: mysql

So far I've got this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IS_ROLEMEMBER (@Rolename VARCHAR(255), @Username VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS BINARY AS 
RETURN ( 
 SELECT (FLOOR(RAND() * 10) % 2) AS BINARY
);
```

But that gives me "wrong syntax by 'RETURN ( SELECT (FLOOR(RAND() * 10) % 2) AS BINARY)'"

ignore the paramters and function name, I want this for testing

Comment: Why do you return `BINARY`? That is not boolean, it's a string type.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you had a couple of errors. Try

```
CREATE FUNCTION IS_ROLEMEMBER (Rolename VARCHAR(255), Username VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS BINARY 
READS SQL DATA
RETURN 
( 
    SELECT (FLOOR(RAND() * 10) % 2)
);
```

The main errors I saw were:

`@Rolename` and `@Username` - no need to use `@`

`RETURNS BINARY AS` - no need for `AS`

I included the `READS SQL DATA` line as this caused an error on my side otherwise. I believe this is related to replication, so depending on your set up you may not need it.

Comment: What are the errors, the `READS SQL DATA`? Is that a necessary part of a function definition?

Comment: sorry, I thought the errors were easy enough to spot. I've clarified them further now.

Comment: Thnx. They may not be easy for everyone ;)

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler:

```
CREATE ...
RETURN INT AS
RETURN RAND() > 0.5
```

And you could change the 0.5 to give a 'bias' to the choice.

(Why have those arguments, if they are not used?)

Learn how to use `DELIMITER`; you are about to get in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

just remove floating precision by rounding RAND() and you get a 1|0, so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `RandomBool` ()
RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN
    RETURN ROUND(RAND());
END
```